# What game is this meeple from?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image: Mystery meeple]

This meeple was found at a bar where board games are often played, but nobody could identify what game it was from. It appears similar to a standard meeple, but with a flat bottom (rather than two separated legs) and a diagonal "hat". Any idea what game it could have come from?

Comment: Seems like Tiny Epic *something* (though not "Western")...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Except for the solid base (no leg split), as The Chaz 2.0 noted in the comments, it looks like a farmer child from the Wooden Farmer Set for Agricola.

See image at https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1841766/agricola-wooden-farmer-set

Comment: Were some of the Agricola children manufactured with flat bottom edges?

Comment: ooh. Good catch. I'll keep looking.